# Dimensionamento de GUI

Tags: java, gui

tudo bom?
Estou fazendo meu primeiro programa em Java. Como eu faço pra ele ser visualmente compatível com qualquer monitor e resolução?
Já tentei fazê-lo uma vez e dessa primeira vez que tentei, fiz os componentes e janelas medindo no meu monitor, mas ficou horrível quando tentei abrir ele na faculdade (monitor maior). Ai joguei tudo fora (se bem me lembro) e resolvi começar do começo.
Utilizei Java Swing no NetBeans, mas descontinuei também por dificuldades com a customização dos elementos, que eu queria, mas não soube como fazer.
Estou usando o Eclipse e decidi refazer no NetBeans, fazendo dois programas iguais simultaneamente, pra ver as diferenças entre um IDE e outro (Mas isso não é importante, eu acho).
Desde já, obrigado!

Comment: Sua pergunta está ampla demais. Adicione o que você já tentou para que fique mais facil responder. E seja mais especifico com "gui", existem varias maneiras de fazer isso em java, informe tambem que tipo de GUI(javafx, swing/awt) está fazendo.

Comment: O truque está em desenhar interfáces gráficas relativas (ao invés de absolutas). Todos os componentes devem defenir uma margem relativa ao seu compenente pai/irmão. Já que não mencionou a bibliotéca gráfica que está a usar, eu aconselhava o [Java fx](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/get-started-tutorial/get_start_apps.htm#JFXST804). Pode encontrar aqui alguns exemplos

Comment: Olha, achei que eram conselhos do próprio Stack Overflow em relação ao que eu escrevi. =P
Não sei o que é Java fx, estou pesquisando. Mas lembro que utilizei Swing e não AWT.

Comment: De qualquer forma, a pergunta está ampla.  é recomendado você primeiro aprender sobre layout managers, eles é que te darão a base para construir janelas relativas.

Comment: Use javaFX, ela e muito boa pra fazer UI redimensionável , ela está cheia de 'binding' ou seja, as coisas se esticam, e ainda possui um algorítimo ótimo de escolha tamanho automático nos 'Nodes'